# geolocation permission popup -jquery

Tags: jquery, geolocation, popup

The popup that asks for user permission to access current location either to block or allow is showing for only 2 seconds it closes even before user could select. I need help in displaying the popup for atleast user to click on it

[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Pur.png)

```
    var listenType = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('edge') == -1) ? 'mouseup' : 'click';
...
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      getZipFromLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      
    }, (err) => {
      if (err.code === err.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        const locationDisabledcontent = `          
        <div class="text-center zip-alert-heading"><b>Location sharing is disabled on your
        browser.</b></div>
      <p class="text-center zip-alert-subheading">Please enable location sharing in your browser settings. <br /> or
      type in a zip code
      to continue.</p>`;
        if ($('.custom-alert')) {
          $('.custom-alert .modal-body').empty();
          $('.custom-alert .modal-body').html(locationDisabledcontent);
          $('.custom-alert').addClass('show');
        }
        $('.custom-alert-close').on('click', function () {
          $('.custom-alert').removeClass('show');
        })
      }
    }, {timeout:5000});
  }
}
...

$('.zipEntry-text').on(listenType, function (e) {
  console.log('in zipentrytext, get current location');
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  getLocation();
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  const zipExists = getCookie('zip');
  if (!zipExists) {
    getLocation();
    const zipExists = getCookie('zip');
    if (!zipExists) {
      getAddressFromZip(defaultZip);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: What's `zipEntry-text`?  Is it a `<button>`?  Sounds like it's a button that's forcing your page to POST and thus reload.  Especially as you're using mouseup and not click, so the default click event is still firing.  Change `<button>` to `<button type='button'>` so it doesn't submit.  See [mcve].

Comment: If you remove the `.on(listenType` and just calling `getLocation()` (outside a function), does it still happen?  Or does the prompt wait for as long as needed?  If it waits, then you can rule out *all* of the geolocation code.

Comment: when we click on that text (zipEntry-text) I get prompt and it stays but I also want prompt on page load which goes very quickly. In both the places, all I am doing is call  getLocation. Why it is acting differently.

Answer (score 0):

Default(getAddressfromzip) is running even before getcurrentlocation returns a value so I set a delay of 10seconds after getLocation so default could not run